# mongodb - writing complex query including ordering in an embedded array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a8ec4620cd3c2a4062548ec"),
"chromosome" : 1,
"start" : "1",
"reference" : "A",
"alternative" : "C",
"populationFrequencies" : [ 
    {
        "study" : "dbnlvar",
        "population" : "GBL",
        "value" : 0.1
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "genomad",
        "population" : "AF",
        "value" : 0.2
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "genomad",
        "population" : "AFR",
        "value" : 0.3
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "genomad",
        "population" : "AMR",
        "value" : 0.4
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "genomad",
        "population" : "ASJ",
        "value" : 0.2
    }
    {
        "study" : "1kg",
        "population" : "GBL",
        "value" : 0.1
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "1kg",
        "population" : "EUR",
        "value" : 0.15
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "1kg",
        "population" : "SAS",
        "value" : 0.10
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "1kg",
        "population" : "AMR",
        "value" : 0.25
    }, 
    {
        "study" : "1kg",
        "population" : "EAS",
        "value" : 0.7
    }
]
}
```

Using this criteria:

1. Study is equal to '1kg'
2. Population is in [EUR,SAS,AMR]

I want to find out documents in the collection that meet that ordering the documents in populationFrecuencies array that meet criteria 1 and 2, by field 'value' from lowest to highest, the second lowest value is bigger than 0.10

So, to clarify, in the following example, the document will be shown.

- Study 1kg - Population SAS - Value 0.10
- Study 1kg - Population EUR - Value 0.15 <--- is bigger than 0.10
- Study 1kg - Population AMR - Value 0.25

Is it possible to express that as a query in mongodb shell?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: It can be done easily using aggregation framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "populationFrequencies":{
      "$elemMatch":{
        "study":"1kg","population":{"$in":["EUR","SAS","AMR"]}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$populationFrequencies"},
  {"$sort":{"populationFrequencies.value":1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","populationFrequencies":{"$push":"$populationFrequencies"}}},
  {"$match":{"$expr":{"$gt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$populationFrequencies.value",1]},0.10]}}}
])
```

Comment: Yes, I had to change a bit your aggregation as I am using mongo 3.4, but definitely it was the solution I was looking for. Thanks Veeram.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) we can get the desired result

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$populationFrequencies"},
   {$match:
      {$and:[
         {"populationFrequencies.study":"1kg"}, 
         {"populationFrequencies.population":
            {$in:["EUR", "SAS", "AMR"]}
         }
      ]}
    },
    {$sort:{"populationFrequencies.value":1}}
])
```

First Using the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) break the `populationFrequencies` array of documents

then using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), here in our scenario we need to use a $and and [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to meet the criteria's

```
1. Study is equal to '1kg'
2. Population is in [EUR,SAS,AMR]
```

Finally use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

Sample output on the above document will be

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ec4620cd3c2a4062548ec"),
        "chromosome" : 1,
        "start" : "1",
        "reference" : "A",
        "alternative" : "C",
        "populationFrequencies" : {
                "study" : "1kg",
                "population" : "SAS",
                "value" : 0.1
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ec4620cd3c2a4062548ec"),
        "chromosome" : 1,
        "start" : "1",
        "reference" : "A",
        "alternative" : "C",
        "populationFrequencies" : {
                "study" : "1kg",
                "population" : "EUR",
                "value" : 0.15
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ec4620cd3c2a4062548ec"),
        "chromosome" : 1,
        "start" : "1",
        "reference" : "A",
        "alternative" : "C",
        "populationFrequencies" : {
                "study" : "1kg",
                "population" : "AMR",
                "value" : 0.25
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, in this way I get the array sorted, but what about checking if the second item has value bigger than 0.10 in order to determine if the query should return the document or not?

Comment: Add the desired condition you want in the $and part of the $match section.

Comment: Not sure I explained well, is after ordering that I have to check that the second item in order has a value bigger than 0.10. Apart from that, should I aggregate the splitted items in the unwind operation to form just a single document again?